# Trying to have a table with unique name for each instance of the application

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, orm

New to databases. Having a problem where I want each instance of the application to have its own database. Trying to figure out how to implement this with the current setup of ORM. Currently using Javax persistence. Does anyone have a solution to this ?

**SIMPLE**: Want to have a unique name for each table

```
    //thread safe
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    public ImageDAOManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }
....
```

```
@Entity
public class ImageDAO implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String path;
    private int fileSize;
    private long date;
    private int imageHeight;
    private int imageWidth;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String tags;

    public ImageDAO(String path, int fileSize, long date, int imageHeight, int imageWidth, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.path = path;
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
        this.date = date;
        this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.tags = "";
    }
```

````
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="LecturePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>backend.database.ImageDAO</class>
        <properties>
            <!--username and password is temporarily here-->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>```
````

Comment: "I want each instance of the application to have its own database." As much as you think you do, you probably don't. There is nothing worse than inheriting a project that has 100,000 different databases and zero ways of managing them.

Comment: @tadman Okey. So lets say I have a imagedatabase and I dont want to share information with another instance of the application. I have 1 instance where I have multiple unique paths and then when I open another instance of the app it will override the currenly saved paths. How would I solve this if not for multiple databases ?

Comment: You're talking about making a multi-tenant application, something that's been done many times before without multiple databases. Normally you just add a column to any table that's tenant-specific, like `tenant_id` or `account_id` and include that as a `WHERE` clause in any query to that table, something your ORM can probably help you with. This might seem like a huge hassle, but it's way less hassle than trying to run migrations on thousands of databases one at a time.

Comment: @tadman Okey thank you for your help. I'll look in too it and come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a new database for each instance of your app is certainly not the right solution. Instead, you should look into multi-tenant applications, I would suggest this article: https://dzone.com/articles/multi-tenancy-using-jpa-spring-and-hibernate-part

In summary, a new database for each instance of your application will severely reduce your performance, capabilities for running historical queries, and potentially issues with concurrency.

A quick fix would be to have a column such as `tenant_id` or even just `instance_id` which would help you ensure that data is queried only for that instance.